# How to set scroll off set in table view when moved up from screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am building a comment screen in iOS.I have main view which has table view to show previous comments & text field to post comments.When main view is moved up when i keyboard comes up then i am not able to scroll the table view from very top of the screen.Initial comments are not visible.please tell how to set offset of scroll view in table view?

**Code to move table view up**

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    // Write code to adjust views accordingly using deltaHeight
    _currentKeyboardHeight = kbSize.height;
    self.nslc_view_top.constant=-_currentKeyboardHeight;
    self.nslc_view_bottom.constant=_currentKeyboardHeight;
    [self.view_container layoutSubviews];




}
```

Comment: Could you include some code on how you are moving the "main view" up? I assume your TableView is inside this MainView, and from the sound of it, you are moving this view up, outside of the ViewController's view bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand your problem but you can scroll your tableview to top like that;

```
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated:true)
```

If your tableview contains whole screen, probably it doesn't work. Then try that;

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```

If your tableView has header, you can also try that;

```
self.tableView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

if all above answer does provide your solution then try with another way

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return 30;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
CGRect frame = tableView.frame;
frame.size.height = 30;
UITextField *myView = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
myView.text = @"this is sample text";
return myView;
}
```

Comment: i want to scrol to top when uitable is moved up from screen

Answer (score -1):

Judging from the code you included, you are setting your topConstant to be outside of the view bounds. Instead, you could leave the topConstant as is, and only change the bottom constant when keyboard is shown/dismissed.